# Angularjs how to get browser history list?

Tags: angularjs, browser, browser-history

I want to remove my history, so I use this code

```
$state.go(toGo, params, {location: 'replace'})
```

When I use this, I could remove the very last history.

And my question is,

how to remove history before the last removed page.

For example,

to see the content of an item, I move into ***detailPage***

Click edit Button to edit this item, and move into ***editPage***.

After I finish editing this, press finish Button, and move into ***detailPage*** again.

In this case, if I use above code, ***editPage*** is removed in history.

But before ***editPage***, there was ***detailPage***, so it acts like ***detailPage*** after ***detailPage***.

In conclusion if I click browser back button, ***detailPage*** showed twice.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you need to remove from the history list? If you don't replace the current history entry (removing `{ location: 'replace' }`), what is the problem?

Related, from MDN Window.History doc (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history) -- 'There is no way to clear the session history or to disable the back/forward navigation from unprivileged code. The closest available solution is the location.replace() method, which replaces the current item of the session history with the provided URL.'

Comment: @Clark And then how do I fix problem duplicated page showing continuously? Could you give me some advice?

Comment: It shouldn't show continuously if you remove `location: replace`.

Comment: @Clark If I remove `location: replace`, call edit Page when back button pressed. But It's not my purpose.

Comment: I gave you an answer to your question -- you no longer see 'detailPage' twice. If that is insufficient, then what is your purpose?

Comment: @Clark Well, If I finished editing in editPage and click button, move to detail page again but don't want to remain editPage in history. so I use `location: replace` to remove editPage in history. But after done this, in history stack, two detailPages remained continuously. Then when if click back button, it seemed like not working but actually page is move from  detailPage to detailPage. So I want to know how to handle these continuously pages like using merge or something